# Please check my solution, number theory

Tags: number-theory, proof-verification

Please evaluate my solution and let me know of anywhere I can improve or make clearer. Thank you

{Problem #41, p. 53:} In 1972, D.C. Kay investigated properties of the following generalized Collatz algorithm given by $a_{n+1} = a_n/p$ if $p \ | \ a_n$ and $a_{n+1} = a_n \cdot q + r$ if  $p \nmid a_n$. Investigate the actions of the generalized algorithm on the positive integers when $(p, q, r) = (2, 5, 1)$.

{Solution: }

Given: 
 \begin{align*}
 a_{n+1} &= \frac{a_n}{p} \text{ if } p \mid  n \\
 a_{n+1} &= a_n \cdot q + r \text{ if } p \nmid n
 \end{align*}

$$(p, q, r) = (2, 5, 1)$$
 \begin{align*}
  \Rightarrow p &= 2 \\
  \Rightarrow q &= 5 \\
  \Rightarrow r &= 1 
 \end{align*}

Now for $p = 2$

\begin{align*}
 p \mid n \Rightarrow 2 \mid n \Rightarrow n &= 2m \text{ for } m \in \mathbb{Z} \\
 p \nmid n \Rightarrow 2 \nmid n \Rightarrow n &= 2m + 1 \text{ for } m \in \mathbb{Z}
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
 \therefore a_{n+1}  &= 
\begin{cases}
  \frac{a_n}{p} & \quad \text{for } n = 2m \\
  a_n \cdot q + r & \quad \text{for } n = 2m + 1
  \end{cases} \\  
  \\
  \Rightarrow a_{2m + 1} &= \frac{a_{2m}}{p} = \frac{a_{2m}}{2} \text{ for } n = 2m \\
  \\
and \ a_{2m + 1 + 1} &= (a_{2m + 1}) \cdot 5 + 1 \text{ for } n = 2m + 1  \\
\\
\Rightarrow a_{2m + 1} &= \frac{a_{2m}}{2} \text{ for } n = \text{even } = 2m
\\
and \ a_{2m + 2} &= 5a_{2m + 1} + 1 \text{ for } n = \text{odd } = 2m + 1
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

You have made a quite basic mistake at the start of your proof. The algorithm gives $2$ different formulas for $a_{n+1}$ based on whether or not $p \mid a_n$. However, you're checking for $p \mid n$ instead. There's no particular reason to expect, and it won't be the case in general, there is any particular correlation between the $2$ situations, i.e., $p$ either divides or doesn't divide $n$ and $a_n$. As such, the rest of your proof's results are not valid.

I'm not quite sure exactly what the question's request to "investigate" is supposed to mean. However, here are a few things to notice in the case where $(p, q, r) = (2, 5, 1)$. First, the general formula now becomes

$$a_{n+1} = 
\begin{cases}
  \frac{a_n}{2} & \quad \text{for } 2 \mid a_n \\
  5a_n + 1 & \quad \text{for } 2 \not\mid a_n
  \end{cases}
\tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

If you express $a_n$ as $2m$ or $2m + 1$, for some positive integer $m$, then since $5(2m + 1) + 1 = 10m + 6$, \eqref{eq1A} becomes

$$a_{n+1} = 
\begin{cases}
  m & \quad \text{for } a_n = 2m \\
  10m + 6 & \quad \text{for } a_n = 2m + 1
  \end{cases}
\tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

As for some aspects of the general behavior, note if $a_n$ is even, say $a_n = 2^j(2k+1)$ where $j \ge 1$ and $k \ge 0$, the first part of \eqref{eq2A} will apply $j$ times until the end result becomes $2k + 1$ (in particular, note if $k = 0$, i.e., $a_n$ is a power of $2$, the result here would be going back to $1$). Then the second part of \eqref{eq2A} will apply giving $10k + 6$, so the the first part applies again to give $5k + 3$. Now, if $k$ is even, then the second part applies to give $5(5k + 3) + 1 = 25k + 16$, which is even, so the first step will be used $1$ or more times. If $k$ is odd, say $k = 2i + 1$, then $5k + 3 = 5(2i + 1) + 3 = 10i + 8$, which is even, so the first step will once again be used $1$ or more times.

The above discussion is qualitatively the same sort of behavior exhibited by the regular Collatz procedure. As for specific cases with the positive integers, the following shows the results for the first several starting integers. Since each later value only depends on the previous value, if a starting integer has already been encountered in a previous set of values, it's set of values will be the same going forward as from the earlier set, so there's no need to repeat them. Thus, I just bypass them to show the results of the next non-used integer. This gives the following ordered sets of $a_i$, where $i$ is the $1$-based index

$$(1, 6, 3, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1, \ldots) \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

$$(5, 26, 13, 66, 33, 166, 83, 416, 208, 104, 52, 26, 13, \ldots) \tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

$$(7, 36, 18, 9, 46, 23, 116, 58, 29, 146, 73, 366, 183, 916, 458, 229, 1146, 573, \ldots) \tag{5}\label{eq5A}$$

The first $2$ sequences show show it eventually becomes periodic, similar to the Collatz conjecture. However, as \eqref{eq4A} shows, in this more general case, the value of $1$ is not always necessarily ever reached. Also, assuming the set of sequence values always eventually becomes periodic (I believe it will, but am not sure if this can be proven and, if even if it can, how to do this) the period length can become quite large, as shown in \eqref{eq5A}. Continuing the sequence values gives $2866$, $1433$, $7166$, $3583$, $17916$, $8958$, $4479$, $22396$, $11198$, $5599$, $27996$, $13998$, $6999$, etc.